# How to write a Python script to open a csv file correctly

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file I cannot read properly because instead of it being comma-separated it has semicolons, therefore I cannot read it as a table.

Do you know if I can write a script in order to see it properly?
Below I typed how I am reading part of the file.

```
;"sid";"aid";"sentnr";"parnr";"sentence";"Subject.party";                                               
1;43160789;74861000;1;1;"Officieel â€žaanzoek"" namens                                                  
2;43160790;74861000;1;2;"Van onze parlementaire redactie  NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA                                      
3;43160791;74861000;2;2;"Hierdoor is de opvolging van                                                   
4;43160792;74861000;3;2;"Dr. Samkalden had in ;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA                                             
5;43160793;74861000;4;2;"In het kabinet-Bi                                  
6;43160794;74861000;5;2;"_";NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA
```

Comment: What's the signifance of the lines of `NA` as this will screw up tokenising

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `csv` module.

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    data = list(reader)
```

Comment: @tobias_k: true, I forgot about delimiter argument.

Comment: Sorry the OP's input data has more tokens than columns so your code won't work

Answer (score 1):

Use the `delimiter` argument to `csv.reader()`;

```
import csv

with open('your_file.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    _ = next(reader)    # skip header row
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

**Output**

```
['1', '43160789', '74861000', '1', '1', 'Officieel \xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc5\xbeaanzoek" namens\n2;43160790;74861000;1;2;Van onze parlementaire redactie  NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA']
['3', '43160791', '74861000', '2', '2', 'Hierdoor is de opvolging van\n4;43160792;74861000;3;2;Dr. Samkalden had in ', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA']
['5', '43160793', '74861000', '4', '2', 'In het kabinet-Bi\n6;43160794;74861000;5;2;_"', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA']
```

This code will split fields on the semicolon as required, however, as pointed out by EdChum, there are other problems with the file, notably the use of unbalanced quotes.

Comment: This won't work the OP's csv has screwed up content and variable tokens and quoting

Comment: @EdChum. Thanks, you're right, but it is at least now splitting the fields based on the semicolon. I have added a note as per your comment.